# atoi and string array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, atoi

I have a string array and an integer array. I want to convert the elements of string array to integer and then store them in the integer array. I wrote this code :

```
string yuzy[360];
int yuza[360];

for(int x = 0;x<360;x++)
{
    if(yuzy[x].empty() == false)
    {

         yuza[x]=atoi(yuzy[x]);
         cout<<yuza[x]<<endl;
    }
    else
        continue;
}
```

this piece of code gives this error:
error: cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int atoi(const char*)'

When I write the content of the string (-75dbm) in atoi function it works fine. But when  I write (yuzy[x]), I get the error. How can I make atoi works well with string array?
Thanks.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but while sticking "-75dbm" does work, it's not terribly good practice. Try to do a bit of cleaning on your number strings before you convert them.

Answer (score 8):

`atoi()` takes C strings (char pointers) and not C++ string objects. Use

```
atoi(yuzy[x].c_str());
```

instead.

Comment: this results in error: `error: request for member ‘c_str’ in ‘a.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator[]<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(1u)’, which is of non-class type ‘char’
  cout<<atoi(a[1].c_str())<<endl;`

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to `atoi`, you could use [std::stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) and related functions, if you have C++11 support.

```
yuza[x] = std::stoi(yuzy[x]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`atoi` accept a c-style string as parametter, so, you could use `atoi(yuzy[x].c_str());`